# How to handle UnsafePointer<Unmanaged<CFArray>?>

Tags: swift

How do I call the following function:

`func AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element: AXUIElement!, names: UnsafePointer<Unmanaged<CFArray>?>) -> AXError`

I have a AXUIElement(Ref) (they are typealias'ed) and I'd like to call the function to get the accessibility attribute names available for that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a little bit guessing (because I have no experience with the Accessibility 
functions), but from the function declaration it should work like this:

```
let element: AXUIElementRef = ...

var ptr : Unmanaged<CFArray>? = nil
let error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, &ptr)
if error == AXError(kAXErrorSuccess) {
    let names = ptr!.takeRetainedValue() // gives a CFArray
    // ...
}
```

**Update for Swift 3** (untested):

```
let element: AXUIElement = ...

var cfArray: CFArray?
let error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, &cfArray)
if error == .success, let names = cfArray as? [String] {
    // names is [String] array ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The important part I was missing was the & operator. Also nice to see how one is supposed to work with those kAX* constants!