# Working with ObjC Functions with UnsafeMutableRawPointer or UnsafeMutablePointer Parameter from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I'm new to swift, and Im trying to work with ObjC function that has a parameter type UnsafeMutablePointer. I read many posts about working with UnsafeMutablePointer or UnsafeMutableRawPointer, but I couldn't still get it to work. The function is:
func AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(_ element: AXUIElement, _ names: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> AXError
I even found the  question for exact function, but the answer does not seem to work any more in swift 3. Here are some of the things that I tried that didn't work.

```
var ptr : Unmanaged<CFArray>? = nil
AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, &ptr)

var names:CFArray? = nil
                    AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, UnsafeMutablePointer(names))

var names:CFArray? = nil
AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, UnsafeMutablePointer<CFArray>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(names).toOpaque()))
```

Also, is there a good tutorial that would give me solid grasp on working with ObjC functions in Swift 3? It seems there are still many apis missing in swift.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124002/how-to-handle-unsafepointerunmanagedcfarray for Swift 3, does that help?

Comment: @Martin R - That totally worked! If you post it as answer, I can accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Martin R - You probably know the answer to this as well. Would you mind looking? This is related to this: getting Swift String from CFTypeRef with ObjC function... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784738/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames` does not take a pointer to
an *unmanaged* `CFArray` anymore:

```
let element: AXUIElement = ...

var cfArray: CFArray?
let error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(element, &cfArray)
if error == .success, let names = cfArray as? [String] {
    // names is [String] array ...
}
```