# Getting Attributes for UI Elements Using AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue Function in Swift3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to get the title of each ui element inside a window using the following function.

```
func AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(_ element: AXUIElement, _ attribute: CFString, _ value: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>) -> AXError
```

However, the function AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue to get AXTitle returns an error. What's the right way to get the values for attributes of UI Elements in swift3? Here's my code.

```
var children:CFTypeRef?
var error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((windows?[0])!, "AXChildren" as CFString, &children)
if error == .success, let elements = children as? [AXUIElement] {
    for element in elements {
        var cfName:CFTypeRef?
        error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((element), "AXTitle" as CFString, &cfName)
        if error == .success {
            let axValue = cfName as! AXValue
            let type = AXValueGetType(axValue)
            var attribute = ""
            var attributePtr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(attribute as AnyObject).toOpaque())
            AXValueGetValue(cfName as! AXValue, type, &attributePtr)
            attribute = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(attributePtr).takeUnretainedValue() as! String
            print("\(attribute)")
        } else {
            NSLog("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
if error == .success, let name = cfName as? String {
   print(name)
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is `msg`? – Apart from that line, your code compiles for me.

Comment: Msg is just regular string variable. var msg:String = ""

Comment: Do you get a compiler error or an error when running the program?

Comment: Actually my bad. It compiles and runs, but no output. it seems like AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue is throwing the error. So, none of the codes get executed after         if error == .success, let name = cfName as? String {

Comment: @Martin R - Is there a way to print the error from the function AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue in console, and find what error that is? Then I could provide more information. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Two things I learned about **AXUI** so far: 1. Reading an attribute of the app process itself during app startup can crash the app and/or gives incorrect results, which makes sense cause the window is about to be created hence the attributes are just being written. 2. If you want to make sure an attribute is readable, request them with `AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames`, although this will also list attributes of the app itself that might crash it (see 1. point).