# Accessing Objective-C Pointers in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers

I have this Objective-C Code fragment, which I want to express in Swift

```
CFArrayRef windowList;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&windowList);

if ((!windowList) || CFArrayGetCount(windowList)<1)
        continue;

AXUIElementRef windowRef = (AXUIElementRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( windowList, 0);
CFTypeRef role;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(windowRef, kAXRoleAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&role);
```

The first thing I´m not sure about: Who allocates the memory behind the windowListPointer. 
I tried with this fragment:

```
var windowListPointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<AnyObject>>
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, windowListPointer );
```

But that does not even compile: It complains, the windowListPointer is not initialised.
What Object I could create, to let the WindowListPointer point to?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124002/how-to-handle-unsafepointerunmanagedcfarray ?

Comment: @MartinR TNT, As in the example `var windowList : CFArray?`
  `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &windowList )` does not compile too: Cannot pass immutable value of type 'CFTypeRef?' (aka 'Optional<AnyObject>') as inout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<AnyObject>>` as the last
argument to `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue()` then you must
initialize it by allocating (and ultimately releasing) memory:

```
var resultPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<AnyObject>> = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)
resultPtr.initialize(to: nil)

let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, resultPtr)
// ...

resultPtr.deinitialize()
resultPtr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

It is easier 
to pass the address of an `Optional<AnyObject>` variable 
with `&`. Then conditionally
cast the received object to the expected type, in this case an
array of `AXUIElement`:

```
var value: AnyObject?
let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)
if result == .success, let windowList = value as? [AXUIElement] {
    // use `windowList`
}
```

and similarly:

```
if let window = windowList.first {
    var value: AnyObject?
    let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(window, kAXRoleAttribute as CFString, &value)
    if result == .success, let role = value as? String {
        // use `role` ...
    }
}
```

---

One could define a generic utility function which encapsulates
all the casting:

```
func axUICopyAttributeValue<T>(of element: AXUIElement, attribute: String, as type: T.Type) -> T? {
    var value: AnyObject?
    let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(element, attribute as CFString, &value)
    if result == .success, let typedValue = value as? T {
        return typedValue
    }
    return nil
}
```

Example usage:

```
if let windowList = axUICopyAttributeValue(of: appRef, attribute: kAXWindowsAttribute, as:[AXUIElement].self) {

    for window in windowList {
        if let role = axUICopyAttributeValue(of: window, attribute: kAXRoleAttribute, as: String.self) {

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Two Questions, 1) where can I find, that I have to cast to `[AXUIElement]` 2) `var value: AnyObject? ` Does that declaration allocate any memory for an Object or just a reference to AnyObject (or nil)

Comment: 1) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/kaxwindowsattribute states that the values is "an array of accessibility objects". – 2) Optional variables are implicitly initialized to `nil`. No memory is allocated there.

Comment: Compiles fine now, but returns `AXError`  . Got the other parameters as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480873/set-the-size-and-position-of-all-windows-on-the-screen-in-swift

Comment: The row value of the AXError is kAXErrorCannotComplete = -25204, Doku says: A fundamental error has occurred, such as a failure to allocate memory during processing. Could it be possible, that I have to allocate anything for `var value: AnyObject?`?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I tested it with a reference to the current application `let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(getpid())`, and that worked.

Comment: The problem was the sandbox. I didn't know, it had to be switched off to "controlling" other apps.

Answer (score 1):

CFArray is the Foundation C version of NSArray (since C doesn't understand Objective C NSObjects).  Swift papers over both NSArray and CFArray for you so you don't need to use a pointer; you should just be able to cast it to a Swift array of the appropriate type with `as?`

Comment: What Swift Type would you use for  windowList in `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, windowList )'