# How to properly use CFStringGetCString in swift?

Tags: swift, cfstring

I am looking at the docs for 
[CFStringGetCString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542721-cfstringgetcstring)
and [AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1462085-axuielementcopyattributevalue).

`CFStringGetCString` takes the param `buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!`
`AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` takes the param `value: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>`

For the latter, I can do a call like this:

```
var value: CFTypeRef?
let err = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(element, attribute as CFString, &value);
```

This satisfies the doc asking for an `UnsafeMutablePointer` of type `CFTypeRef`.

However I can't get the same logic to apply by doing

```
let buffer: Int8!
CFStringGetCString(attribute as! CFString, &buffer, 2048, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue)
```

I also tried

```
let buffer: Int8?
CFStringGetCString(attribute as! CFString, &buffer!, 2048, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue)
```

Either way, it complains about using `buffer` before it's initialized, even though it never complained about `value` in the working method with similar param requirements.

All the working examples I've seen for `CFStringGetCString` are using objective-c like syntax with `*`. Not sure what the proper swift way is here.

I also tried this way to get the value I wanted:

```
let app = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
var valueString = "";

var value: CFTypeRef?
// An exception on execution happens here when passing app
// Passing in the element I clicked instead of app
// yields error -25205 (attributeunsupported)
let err = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(app, "AXFocusedApplication" as CFString, &value);
if (err == AXError.success) {
    valueString = value! as! NSString as String;
} else {
    print("ERROR!");
    print(err.rawValue);
}

return valueString;
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487193/accessing-objective-c-pointers-in-swift ?

Comment: @MartinR that basically shows how to do what I did, which worked for `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue`. There is some extra complication between an `Int8` and `CFString` for `UnsafeMutablePointer` I can't figure out. I can't really initialize to `nil` in this case.

Comment: There should be no need to use CFStringGetCString in Swift. You can (conditionally) *cast* the value to `String`. – What do you need the C string for?

Comment: @MartinR I posted the solution I had originally tried before looping back to `CFStringGetCString` which is what I had seen used in C++

Comment: Did you try `if let valueString = value as? String { print(valueString) }` (as in the referenced Q&A)?

Comment: @MartinR that is not the issue. I get an error before attempting to do anything to `valueString`. `err` is returned from `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` with the code I mentioned in sample above. `valueString` is not used in that method.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. If `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue()` returns an error, what has that to do with how to call `CFStringGetCString()`?

Comment: @MartinR I tried getting the value via `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue`, but it doesn't support this attribute. That is the thing being used in the article you posted. When that failed, I figured I can use `CFStringGetCString`, but am stumbling over the proper creation of the buffer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191115/discussion-between-martin-r-and-dave-stein).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you torturing yourself with `CFStringGetCString`? If you have a `CFString` in Swift, you can cast it to a `String` and get a C string from that:

```
let cString: [Int8] = (cfString as String).cString(using: .utf8)!
```

Note also that the value of the `kAXFocusedApplicationAttribute` is **not** a `CFString`. It is an `AXUIElement`.

Here's my playground test:

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation

let axSystem = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
var cfValue: CFTypeRef?
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(axSystem, kAXFocusedApplicationAttribute as CFString, &cfValue)
if let cfValue = cfValue, CFGetTypeID(cfValue) == AXUIElementGetTypeID() {
    let axFocusedApplication = cfValue
    print(axFocusedApplication)
}
```

The first time I executed this playground, I got a system dialog box telling me that I need to give Xcode permission to control my computer. I went to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility, found Xcode at the bottom of the list, and turned on its checkbox.

Here's the output of the playground:

```
<AXUIElement Application 0x7fb2d60001c0> {pid=30253}
```

I assume you're on macOS since the AXUI API is only available on macOS. If you just want the name of the front application as a string, you can do this:

```
if let frontAppName = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication?.localizedName {
    print(frontAppName)
}
```

Comment: I was gonna come back and write that I learned about that `kAXFocusedApplicationAttribute` constant but you beat me to updating the question :)